# GWT JsType array casting

Tags: javascript, gwt, gwt-jsinterop

When I have JSON object like:

```
{
    "asset": {
        "properties": [{
            "name": "xxx",
            "id": "yy"
        }]
    }
}
```

Then I have JsInterop wrappers like so:

```
@JsType
public class Asset {

   @JsProperty
   public native jsinterop.base.JsArrayLike<Property> getProperties();

}
```

and:

```
@JsType
public class Property {

   @JsProperty
   public native String getName();
   @JsProperty
   public native String getId();
}
```

When somewhere in code I try to access the data, it fails when I try to access the attributes of the Property object.

For example:

```
Asset asset = dataProvider.getAssets();
console.log(assets) //works ok: => {"properties":Array(1)}
console.log(asset.getProperties()) //works ok:  => Array(1)
console.log(asset.getProperties().getAt(0)) //works ok:  => {"name":"xxx","id":"yy"}
console.log(asset.getProperties().getAt(0).getName() //does not work:  => Uncaught exception: undefined
```

OR if I make the Asset and Property class (isNative=true):

```
Uncaught exception: Cannot read property "company" of undefined.
```

I checked and if I compile the app when I try to get the name or the id, the code compiles to:

```
castTo(asset.properties[0], 125)
```

OR if (isNative=true):

```
castToNative(asset.properties[0], $wnd.com.company.project.Property)
```

First I thought its because of my implementation of the wrapper for array, but the I discovered the "jsinterop.base.JsArrayLike", so I thought that will solve my problem, but the error remained the same. Am I missing someting? I would really like to use JsInterop instead of JSNI methods and Overlay types, but I cannot get past these arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're handling data from JSON, you get plain old `Object` and `Array` objects. So you need to use

```
@JsType(isNative=true, namespace=JsPackage.GLOBAL, name="Object")
```

**or** you could use interfaces instead, which won't do casts and type checks.

Comment: Awesome, it works, I thought the "name" should be the Java name, not that all have to have the same "Object" name :) And if I use interfaces the method wouldn't have the "native" keyword and the annotation could be just @JsType(isNative=true) ?

Comment: OK I tried it even with the interfaces and it works flawlessly, thanks